# How to check whether I am enter or exit in geofence region in ionic 3

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, geofencing

In my project I have set any particular location latitude longitude when I am adding geofence,how can I check whether I am enter in geofence or exit geofence.

```
     private addGeofence() {
         let fence = {
         id: '69ca1b88-6fbe-4e80-a4d4-ff4d3748acdb', //any unique ID
         latitude:       20.115617, //center of geofence radius
        longitude:     73.859157,
        radius:         100, //radius to edge of geofence in meters
        transitionType: 3, //see 'Transition Types' below
        notification: 
             { //notification settings
                 id:  1, //any unique ID
                 title: 'You crossed a fence', //notification title
                 text: 'You just arrived to Gliwice city center.', //notification body
               openAppOnClick: true //open app when notification is tapped
            }
     }
    this.geofence .addOrUpdate(fence).then(
       () =>{
        console.log('Geofence added')
        this.CheckGeofenceTansition();
       } ,
       (err) => console.log('Geofence failed to add')
     );
 }

CheckGeofenceTansition()
         {
           console.log("geofence on transition recieved Method Called");
           if(this.geofence.onTransitionReceived())
             {
                alert("you are in geofence")
                this.navCtrl.push(NavigationMenuPage)
             }
         else{
             alert("you are out of geofence");
            }
   }
```

Comment: Nupur, Any soln you got for this ?

Comment: Yes I have found solution on this,I used flag which i set false at 1st time, in method transition received I make it true, so if it is true, then user will login successful

Comment: @ Nupur is it working in background ?